# Every time I push my Django project to Elastic Beanstalk, after that I cannot SSH using Putty anymore

Tags: django, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, putty

I am using Django, my Development server is Windows, and I am using Putty to SSH to the EC2 instance.
When I create an Elastic Beanstalk environment, I also create a key pair and assign it to that EBS setting. But, every time I use git aws.push, and push my code to Elastic Beanstalk, after that I cannot SSH using Putty and the same key pair anymore.
However, when I assign a new key pair to the EBS environment, I can SSH again, though it terminates my EC2 instance and creates a new one which results in losing my previous settings.

I searched to find a tutorial on how to deploy a Django project on EC2 and DBS, without using EBS, but the only document that Amazon has is about how to deploy it on EBS.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the security key (pem) committed in your repository? is it possible it simply overrides the existing one in the EC2 instance?  
also, are you on vpc?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk creates a config file in the repository. Other than that I have not copied the pem file in the repository.

Comment: what's the error message you get?

Comment: Server refused our key

Comment: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Comment: try to ssh to the box, then aws.push from your desktop and see if the ssh connection disconnects. If it does, it means your EB config file is changing your security rules.

Comment: No. When I am connected to the EC2 instance via SSH using putty, I can aws.push as many times as I like, and nothing happens, and I can continue using the shell on EC2, but as soon as I close the putty, I am not able to connect it anymore.

Comment: So it doesn't sound like a security settings but rather a changed keypair indeed. Try to find out which end is changing, your client or server. Your server keys can be seen at `cat .ssh/authorized_keys` while your client wherever you saved the pem file. Now `aws.push` and see which end changes. even a file date change is important, as the client end must be with certain permissions.

Comment: Where should I run cat .ssh/authorized_keys? I ran it on the EC2 shell, and it returned: cat: .ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory